# Is the canonical projection $p: X \times X \rightarrow X$ a covering map of the topological space $X$?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, projection

Is the canonical projection $p: X \times X \rightarrow X$ a covering map of the topological space $X$? I would say it satisfies the definition.

For instance: $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It is not a covering, but it is something more general called a "fiber bundle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unless $X$ is discrete. Note that each fibre $X\simeq p^{-1}(a)$ has to be discrete for it to be a covering map, or put in another way, $p$ is in general not a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. In the example, is that equivalent to saying that each fibre $p^{-1}(x)=\mathbb{R}$ isn’t an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Not really. It's that you cannot find any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open subsets that are homeomorphic to $U$. But the single fibre $p^{-1}(x)$ isn't necessarily open (indeed closed if $X$ is Hausdorff), we only know it must be discrete.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.